# String cannot be cast to Object

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I have a class in which i declare this:

```
public class Comune implements Serializable {
    public String id;
    public String name;

    public Comune(String id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

then another class like:

```
public class Comuni {

    public static final Comune[] comuni = {
        new Comune("A093|AGUGLIARO|1","AGUGLIARO"),
        new Comune("A154|ALBETTONE|1","ALBETTONE"),
    ---
    ---
    };
}
```

then i have a fragment with 2 spinners and a button. When i click in the spinner (is an autocompletetextview where appears the spinner in there) it shows the list of "Comune" and i can choose the item i want. When i have the two values of the two autocompletetextview and click in the button i pass in the second screen passing with a putExtra the 2 values of the spinners like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SceltaFermateActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(SceltaFermateActivity.EXTRA_COMUNE_PARTENZA, itemPartenze);
                    intent.putExtra(SceltaFermateActivity.EXTRA_COMUNE_ARRIVO, itemArrivi);
                    startActivity(intent);
```

I tried to implement an sqlite in which i am able to save the 2 values of the spinner in a listview so i can show the "last result". To retrieve the values from the listview i use the cursor like:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
             public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                   Cursor cursor = (Cursor) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                   String item_partenza = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(mdb.KEY_PARTENZA));
                   String item_arrivo = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(mdb.KEY_ARRIVO));


                   /*String item = String.valueOf(item_id) + " : " + item_partenza +"\n"+item_arrivo;
                   Toast.makeText(getActivity(), item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/
             }
         });
```

and it works! The problem is that i would on click on the listview item pass the two values directly so on Click it will open the second screen. But if i pass

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SceltaFermateActivity.class);
                   intent.putExtra(SceltaFermateActivity.EXTRA_COMUNE_PARTENZA, item_partenza);
                   intent.putExtra(SceltaFermateActivity.EXTRA_COMUNE_ARRIVO, item_arrivo);
                   startActivity(intent);
```

it crashes because it says: `String cannot be cast` solutions? Maybe a way to put the strings in the AutoCompleteTextView when i click on the item?

log:

```
04-20 00:54:48.284: E/AndroidRuntime(29566): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-20 00:54:48.284: E/AndroidRuntime(29566): Process: com.dd.ftv, PID: 29566
04-20 00:54:48.284: E/AndroidRuntime(29566): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dd.ftv/com.dd.ftv.SceltaFermateActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to it.ftv.app.model.Comune
04-20 00:54:48.284: E/AndroidRuntime(29566):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
04-20 00:54:48.284: E/AndroidRuntime(29566):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
04-20 00:54:48.284: E/AndroidRuntime(29566):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
04-20 00:54:48.284: E/AndroidRuntime(29566):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
04-20 00:54:48.284: E/AndroidRuntime(29566):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-20 00:54:48.284: E/AndroidRuntime(29566):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
04-20 00:54:48.284: E/AndroidRuntime(29566):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5223)
04-20 00:54:48.284: E/AndroidRuntime(29566):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-20 00:54:48.284: E/AndroidRuntime(29566):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
04-20 00:54:48.284: E/AndroidRuntime(29566):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
04-20 00:54:48.284: E/AndroidRuntime(29566):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
04-20 00:54:48.284: E/AndroidRuntime(29566):    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:117)
04-20 00:54:48.284: E/AndroidRuntime(29566): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to it.ftv.app.model.Comune
04-20 00:54:48.284: E/AndroidRuntime(29566):    at com.dd.ftv.SceltaFermateActivity.onCreate(SceltaFermateActivity.java:72)
04-20 00:54:48.284: E/AndroidRuntime(29566):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
04-20 00:54:48.284: E/AndroidRuntime(29566):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
04-20 00:54:48.284: E/AndroidRuntime(29566):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
04-20 00:54:48.284: E/AndroidRuntime(29566):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: post the full crash log

Comment: @panini have you got any news?

Comment: what type is `SceltaFermateActivity.EXTRA_COMUNE_PARTENZA` and `SceltaFermateActivity.EXTRA_COMUNE_ARRIVO`?  Are those Strings?

Comment: It's a string in the next activity: public static final String EXTRA_COMUNE_PARTENZA = "comunePartenza";

Comment: this one line 72: comunePartenza = (Comune) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(EXTRA_COMUNE_PARTENZA);

Comment: When you call `intent.putExtra(SceltaFermateActivity.EXTRA_COMUNE_PARTENZA, item_partenza);`, is `item_partenza` a String?

Comment: What I see in your code is in your list item click you are passing two strings and converting it to "Comune" object in other screen. 

To get string in other screen you just need to do :- getIntent().getExtras().getString("StringKey"). Don't understand why you are converting it to "Comune " Object. Let me know if I could not understand your question.

Comment: I think that the main problem is that if i choose the value from the adapter f the AutoCompleteTextView it works (because i choose the item of the adapter of Comuni) but if i try to "force" the value not choosing from the adapter it crashes.. Something like that